# In PHP how to parse database data into various tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to php. I have following type of database table data which I want to display in PHP. Table data is available in a variable "**Outputdata**"

[image]

**Now I want to display this data in php in the following way.**

[image]

Product ID should not be repeated and "**Child Columns**" should be nested on the basis of "**category**".

**Following is my code:**
**Model.php Code:**

```
public function getproddata() 
{
    $Outputdata=$this->query("CALL Product();");
    return $Outputdata;
}
```

**Controller COde:**

```
    public function Procdata() {
    $Outputdata=$this->Systemstate->getproddata($testId);
    $this->set('Outputdata',$Outputdata);
 }
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<div class='data1'>
<table class='data11 defaultTable'>
    <th colspan='2'>Data <?php echo $i ?></th>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Product ID" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $current['Product ID'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "Percentage" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $current['Percentage'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <div class='diagnose_toggle' onClick='toggleDiagnose($i)' id='detailsButton$i'></div>
        <table id='details$i' class='defaultTable'>

         <tr>
         <th><?php echo "Category ID" ?></th>
         <th><?php echo "Child Category ID"?></th>
         <th><?php echo "Child Category Name"?></th>

         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><?php echo $current['Category ID']?></td>
         <td><?php echo $current['Child Category ID']?></td>
         <td><?php echo $current['Child Category Name']?></td>

         </tr>
        </table>


        <?php $i++; ?>
```

**Database Query:**

```
    Select Product_ID, Percentage, CategoryID, Child_Categ_ID, Child_categ_name
from products order by Product_ID, CategoryID
```

Problem is all product ids are displayed in separate rows and no nesting is also there.

Any idea to add the nesting and grouping logic?
Thank you

Comment: Please show your database query code.

Comment: Database query is added @AVProgrammer

Comment: I meant the PHP code too. Assuming you are getting the results in manner typical (nested array), you probably have to do nested looping to get all the data out: `for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) foreach($results[$i] as $field_name => $field_value) ... `

Comment: @AVProgrammer actually its cakephp framework and I have created a Model.php file which just call a procedure and in controller i return the value to front end

Comment: @AVProgrammer I have added the rest of the php code

Comment: Thanks I have used general programming methods to use the variables arrays and solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

``assuming for  your 1st table your query is a select all query you would get all values in an array   then user foreach loop
    var_dump will help you view your query that you captured

```
foreach  ($variable as $key as $value){
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $value->column_name1 ?><td>
<td><?php echo $value->column_name2 ?><td>
<td><?php echo $value->column_name3 ?><td>
<td><?php echo $value->column_name4 ?><td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

if fetching from 2 tables  if (primary key == foreign  ) use && inside on how precise you want to filter

Comment: Actually I have all the data present and I have viewed it as well,

I am looking for the nesting logic as shown in fingure 2